# C/C++ fast 3d model parsing

Tags: c++, performance, parsing, model, scanf

I've been trying to parse a directx .x file without using the directX API to load only the geometry of the model. I first tried using C++ streams, but it took almost 3 seconds to parse a 800Kb file. So i tried to do the same with C I/O functions and now it takes about 120 milliseconds.
The problem is that loading the same file with the DX API takes the same or almost same time, but it also loads everything and not only the geometry. So i think that there's something inefficient with my parser, that is only loading the geometry. With a profiler i noticed most of the time is spent on fscanf(), that i use to parse the vertices and indices. i also tried getting every line on a buffer and then using sscanf, but the time was the same. I'm not using STL.
Any suggestions for how to do a faster parsing avoiding the use of fscanf? Please don't say "use another library like Assimp" because i'd like to do that myself.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If Assimp or any other open source library does what you want, analyse it to see why it's faster than your code.

Comment: Thank you for your comment . I've actually looked at the source of assimp, but being it a complete loading library it's difficut to find the revelant parts of the code. But I'll surely check it again, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separate reading from scanning, e.g. first read the whole file into memory (or use memory mapping), then scan with sscanf or whatever (boost::spirit, why not?)

Comment: I tried loading the entire file into a memory buffer, and then processing it with sscanf, but turns out that sscanf is as slow as fscanf. Are there any improvements i could make? I tried writing my own string parser but it's kind of slow. I really wonder how the DX API handles file loading/parsing. Maybe multithreading?

Comment: Multithreading won't work here, becuase there are no big batches to parallelize. Another thing to mention is to profile your load - are you sure it is scanf that takes most of CPU time and not some silly mistake (e.g. memory re-allocation on every new element)?

Comment: Nope, memory allocation is made only for the initial buffer, the array of vertices and indices, only once per file. I replaced scanf with custom parsing + custom atof(), and this speeded up the process a lot. Now it takes about 50ms to process the same file.